# How to change UISplitVIew's TableView Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an ipad app in portrait mode but due to shorter width of DetailView it is hiding content in it according to width wise. SO i want to shorter the width of table view. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple and easy feature of IOS 8.**

In your .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat maximumPrimaryColumnWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

In your .m file:

```
 self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 100;
 self.splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth;
```

Comment: I have an CollectionView in DetailView i want its trailing width less then 16 pts from Detail view.

Comment: - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                       layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 16;
    }

Comment: One more thing i do not want navigation bar above tableview any idea??

Comment: Set the navigation bar's translucent property to NO:.. like

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;